# SQL - retrieve how many post a user has made

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `test_opplegg` with posts. And one column is `test_opplegg.UserId`. Now when I am printing out every post I also want to make a variable `NumOpp` that counts how many post the user/author of this post has made in total.

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT test_opplegg.Title, test_opplegg.id as oid, test_opplegg.Desc, test_opplegg.ShortDesc,test_opplegg.Type, test_opplegg.Approved, test_opplegg.Language, 
                        test_opplegg.Grade, test_opplegg.UserId, test_opplegg.Subject, test_opplegg.Link, test_users.id,  test_users.user_Username,  test_users.user_Name,
                        DATE_FORMAT(test_opplegg.TimeAdded,GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')) as TimeAdded,
                        SUM(test_thumbs.IntValue) AS SumThumbs, 
                        SUM(CASE WHEN test_thumbs.OId = test_opplegg.Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumThumbs,
                        SUM(CASE WHEN test_opplegg.UserId = test_opplegg.UserId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumOpp

                        FROM `test_opplegg` 
                        INNER JOIN test_users ON test_opplegg.UserId = test_users.id 
                        LEFT JOIN test_thumbs ON test_thumbs.OId = test_opplegg.Id GROUP BY test_opplegg.Id
                        ORDER BY id desc;");
```

Is this possible to write a SQL-sentence which counts the number of posts by one author when it is in the same table?

Here is a simplified version of the table:

```
| id | Title | Desc | UserId |
|  1 | ....  | .... |   3    |
|  2 | ....  | .... |   3    |
|  3 | ....  | .... |   2    |
|  4 | ....  | .... |   2    |
|  5 | ....  | .... |   3    |
|  6 | ....  | .... |   5    |
|  7 | ....  | .... |   4    |
```

Here I want to print all .id, but for each .id I print I also want to print how many posts UserId have made in total. When I print post (id = 1) I want to get that UserId (3) has made 3 post in total. 
When I print post (id = 7) I want to get the total number of post made by User (UserId 4), and UserId= 4 have made only 1 post. So then it should print 1.

So can i get the the total number of post made by the author?

Comment: I'm sure that "sentence" does produce incorrect results. The same field will always be equal to itself.

Comment: to count posts number you need to use group by clause on userId, not on post id

Comment: Well, I also need to group by post id too, because of `NumThumbs`

Why does it say -1 next to my post?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hope this is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT test_opplegg.Title, test_opplegg.id as oid, test_opplegg.Desc, test_opplegg.ShortDesc,test_opplegg.Type, test_opplegg.Approved, test_opplegg.Language, 
                        test_opplegg.Grade, test_opplegg.UserId as uidaa, test_opplegg.Subject, test_opplegg.Link, test_users.id,  test_users.user_Username,  test_users.user_Name,
                        DATE_FORMAT(test_opplegg.TimeAdded,GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')) as TimeAdded,
                        SUM(test_thumbs.IntValue) AS SumThumbs, 
                        SUM(CASE WHEN test_thumbs.OId = test_opplegg.Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumThumbs,

                        (SELECT COUNT(test_opplegg.UserId) FROM test_opplegg WHERE test_opplegg.UserId = uidaa) AS NumOpp
                        FROM `test_opplegg` 
                        INNER JOIN test_users ON test_opplegg.UserId = test_users.id 
                        LEFT JOIN test_thumbs ON test_thumbs.OId = test_opplegg.Id GROUP BY test_opplegg.Id, test_opplegg.UserId
                        ORDER BY id desc;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT test_opplegg.Title,
       test_opplegg.id as oid,
       test_opplegg.Desc,
       test_opplegg.ShortDesc,
       test_opplegg.Type,
       test_opplegg.Approved,
       test_opplegg.Language,
       test_opplegg.Grade,
       test_opplegg.UserId,
       test_opplegg.Subject,
       test_opplegg.Link,
       test_users.id,
       test_users.user_Username,
       test_users.user_Name,
       DATE_FORMAT( test_opplegg.TimeAdded,
                    GET_FORMAT( DATE,
                                'EUR' ) ) AS TimeAdded,
       SUM( test_thumbs.IntValue ) AS SumThumbs,
       SUM( CASE
                WHEN test_thumbs.OId = test_opplegg.Id THEN
                    1
                ELSE
                    0
            END ) AS NumThumbs,
       countOfUserIDFinder.countOfUserID AS NumOpp
FROM test_opplegg
JOIN test_users ON test_opplegg.UserId = test_users.id
LEFT JOIN test_thumbs ON test_thumbs.OId = test_opplegg.Id
JOIN ( SELECT UserId
              COUNT( UserId ) AS countOfUserID
       FROM test_opplegg
       GROUP BY UserId
     ) AS countOfUserIDFinder ON test_opplegg.UserId = countOfUserIDFinder.UserId
GROUP BY test_opplegg.Id
ORDER BY id desc;
```

This statement builds upon the one from your Question by adding an `INNER JOIN` to the table generated by the following segment...

```
SELECT UserId
       COUNT( UserId ) AS countOfUserID
FROM test_opplegg
GROUP BY UserId
```

This segment generates a list of each `UserId` and their associated count of posts.  Joining it to your code will have the effect of adding a field to the data on each post that contains the number of posts for the `UserId` associated with that post.  When selected this value is called `NumOpp`.  The segment you were previously using to compute `NumOpp` has been replaced.

If you have any questions of Comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: I get this error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute()`. 
But a new Select * -sentence is the only way of solving it?

Comment: I shall investigate the error.  One way in which you can improve this Question (and future databasing questions) is to provide a script that will generate and populate sample tables of data that we can use to test the code we develop.  This makes life easier for everyone (in part) because it reduces the need to shoot messages back and forth when debugging code.

Comment: Try removing the semicolon (`;`) from the end of my statement (as per the first `Note` from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: Still dont work.
Is it any special tool for "provide a script that will generate and populate sample tables of data that we can use to test the code we develop"?

Comment: I shall continue to investigate.  In some development environments there is such a tool.  You will have to research if your development environment has one.